# Is it possible to set different accounts for different Google sites?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

Let's say I want to use `x@gmail.com` for Gmail, `y@gmail.com` for Firebase. Is this possible, or do I have to logout and select a different account **every single time**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be logged on to multiple Google accounts at the same time; this includes simultaneous access to different Gmail accounts.

Once logged, you need to click the avatar and add account.

When you are logged on to multiple accounts and authorise with OAuth to another site, you'll be asked to choose which account you want to use for that particular site.

You don't need to log off.

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: What's SSHD? never heard of it

Comment: Sorry, I replied under wrong message :-)